# How do I get myself into a routine?

Tags: toddler, daily-routine

I am not good with routine. As a result my two yr old is hard to teach. Also i am not sure what to do. He is has a blood disorder so daycare isnt an option. I cant get him to listen or sit long enough to teach him. He just starting to say words he is in development training because i feel he has a delay. And I've learned it's more me that is his problem than him. Please help with suggestions on what i can do.

Comment: Update the post with the actual age and what you are doing, what he is not doing, and what you expect him to be doing. I don't know if anyone is prepared for the parent thing at first. You figure it out and work through it. Read to him. Show him everything. Build blocks, play, and have fun showing him fun things. You will probably find out how much more you enjoy doing these things that whatever else you would be doing. But try not to think that you're not good at it. You're already putting out a lot of energy keeping up with a toddler.

Comment: What state are you in?  2 years is  pretty young and it would be best to get a professional assessment done.  There are a lot of free resources available, I'd be happy to do a quick search for your state if you want.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're not alone. I am terrible at staying on schedule. My advice: make a chart. Make a list of all the things you need to do or have done and when. You get some poster board or a dry erase board and mapit all out. At first when you start it, warning, you will be tired. Everything will fall into place and soon it will feel natural. Reward yourself for following the chart. Relish in even the smallest of victories. Also, relax, don't stress too much. Also give rewards to everyone in your home that follows the schedule chart now that previously didn't. It will help them grow. (emotionally, confidence, self esteem, etc.) Have fun and don't dwell on the little things. I can't really help with the other stuff because I don't have enough information on the situation. Keep your head up.
 Joni